# CKEditor automatically nesting double ul

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I wrote a plugin for CKEditor 4 that uses widget and dialog. My widget, simplifying a little bit, consists of a `div` with a nested `ul` and a number of `li`'s. For some reason, when I switch from WYSIWYG mode to SOURCE mode, the `ul` is turned into a double nested `ul`.

I have defined which elements in the widget should be editables and I have defined which elements should be allowedContent for those editables.

My original structure in WYSIWYG mode (after the dialog closes and the widget is created) is like this:

```html
<div class="mycustombox">
  <div class="conditions-box">
    <div class="conditions-services">
      <span class="rwd-line-title">TITLE FOR THE UNORDERED LIST</span>
      <ul class="services-list">
        <li>an example list item</li>
        <li>another example list item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have double checked that this is the actual html by inspecting the source of the page in the Chrome Developer Console. But when I switch to SOURCE mode, the structure then becomes:

```html
<div class="mycustombox">
  <div class="conditions-box">
    <div class="conditions-services">
      <span class="rwd-line-title">TITLE FOR THE UNORDERED LIST</span>
      <ul class="services-list">
        <ul>
          <li>an example list item</li>
          <li>another example list item</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The original `ul` with the class I gave it is there, but there is an extra nested `ul` wrapping the `li` elements.

I have defined my allowed widget content in the **plugin.js**:

```json
allowedContent: 'div(!mycustombox); div(!conditions-box); div(!conditions-services); span(!rwd-line); span(!rwd-line-title); ul(!services-list); li; p; div',
requiredContent: 'div(mycustombox)',
upcast: function( element ) {
    return element.name == 'div' && element.hasClass( 'mycustombox' );
},
```

And I have defined the ul element as an editable like so:

```json
editables: {
  priceincludes: {
    selector: 'div.conditions-box div.conditions-services ul',
    allowedContent: 'li em strong'
  },
}
```

I have also allowed ul's to be editable by the general CKEditor instance as so:

```javascript
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable[ 'ul' ] = 1;
```

Is there some setting in the CKEditor configuration which could be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works.
Tell CKEDitor to stop trying to automatically wrap `li` elements with a `ul` tag. For some reason it's treating them as though they weren't already wrapped in a `ul` tag.
Using this at the beginning of my **plugin.js** fixes the problem:

```javascript
    delete CKEDITOR.dtd.$listItem['li'];
    delete CKEDITOR.dtd.$intermediate['li'];
```

I got the idea from here:
http://margotskapacs.com/2014/11/ckeditor-stop-altering-elements/

Seems kind of hackish to me, but until I find a better solution I'll just use this.